# Reactjs Instant search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON schema which I'm mapping through the page and then rendering. Now I want to filter through an only search query and render only the search results.

`Listing.jsx`

```
    <div id="searchbar">
      <Hero>
        <Section>
          <Container>
            <Heading style={{ color: "white" }}>SEARCH</Heading>
            <Field>
              <Control>
                <Input
                  onChange={this.onChangeSearch}
                  name="query"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter query"
                  value={query}
                />
              </Control>
            </Field>
          </Container>
        </Section>
      </Hero>
    </div>
<div>
{pageItems.map(data => (
            <div key={data.id}>
              {data.status === true ? (....) : (...)}</div>}
```

How can I show only relevant search results in instant search/real-time search?

As per comments/suggestions, I'd like the search based on a specific array or entire JSON object to search.

This is my `onChange` event which returns the whole JSON object in the console.

```
  onChangeSearch = evt => {
    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
    });

    this.state.items.map(data => {
      return console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

Comment: It depends on the type of search you're doing. Are you doing a complete look up of the search term, a partial look up like suggestions, etc?

Comment: Depends on how smart your search should be. Should it just check on one field, or multiple. How should it behave on spaces, special characters. Whatever you can think of.

Comment: @Hespen let's say I've to iterate through one array of every JSON object

Comment: @CupofJava I've updated the question with extensive information and added code for `onChange` event, please have a look